# How I turn these classes to override or how I give this final tag to values?

Tags: flutter

I' ve downloaded this plugin recently and I tried to open example file. However I was getting these errors

*This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: StartMeetingWidget.zoomOptions, StartMeetingWidget.meetingOptions, StartMeetingWidget.timer

```
    class StartMeetingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ZoomOptions zoomOptions;
  ZoomMeetingOptions meetingOptions;

  Timer timer;

  StartMeetingWidget({Key key, meetingId}) : super(key: key) {
    this.zoomOptions = new ZoomOptions(
      domain: "zoom.us",
      appKey: "appKey",
      appSecret: "appSecret",
    );
    this.meetingOptions = new ZoomMeetingOptions(
        userId: '<zoom_user_id>',
        displayName: 'Example display Name',
        meetingId: meetingId,
        zoomAccessToken: "<User zak>",
        zoomToken: "<user_token>",
        disableDialIn: "true",
        disableDrive: "true",
        disableInvite: "true",
        disableShare: "true",
        noAudio: "false",
        noDisconnectAudio: "false");
  }

  bool _isMeetingEnded(String status) {
    var result = false;

    if (Platform.isAndroid)
      result = status == "MEETING_STATUS_DISCONNECTING" ||
          status == "MEETING_STATUS_FAILED";
    else
      result = status == "MEETING_STATUS_IDLE";

    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the Todo to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Loading meeting '),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: ZoomView(onViewCreated: (controller) {
            print("Created the view");

            controller.initZoom(this.zoomOptions).then((results) {
              print("initialised");
              print(results);

              if (results[0] == 0) {
                controller.zoomStatusEvents.listen((status) {
                  print("Meeting Status Stream: " +
                      status[0] +
                      " - " +
                      status[1]);
                  if (_isMeetingEnded(status[0])) {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    timer?.cancel();
                  }
                });

                print("listen on event channel");

                controller
                    .startMeeting(this.meetingOptions)
                    .then((joinMeetingResult) {
                  timer = Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
                    controller
                        .meetingStatus(this.meetingOptions.meetingId)
                        .then((status) {
                      print("Meeting Status Polling: " +
                          status[0] +
                          " - " +
                          status[1]);
                    });
                  });
                });
              }
            }).catchError((error) {
              print("Error");
              print(error);
            });
          })),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A final field is a field that can't be reassigned; this means you have to give it a value and never change that value again.

To make a field final, use the `final` keyword:

```dart
class StartMeetingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ZoomOptions zoomOptions;
  final ZoomMeetingOptions meetingOptions;

  final Timer timer;
```

This poses a problem, because you assign these variables on different points.

Both the `ZoomOptions` and `ZoomMeetingOptions` variables get assigned when you create the object, this isn't wrong per se, but you are doing it on the body, which you shouldn't do, instead, use the space before the body (sorry, don't know what to call it):

```
StartMeetingWidget({Key key, meetingId})
  : zoomOptions = new ZoomOptions(
    domain: "zoom.us",
    appKey: "appKey",
    appSecret: "appSecret",
  ),
  meetingOptions = new ZoomMeetingOptions(
      userId: '<zoom_user_id>',
      displayName: 'Example display Name',
      meetingId: meetingId,
      zoomAccessToken: "<User zak>",
      zoomToken: "<user_token>",
      disableDialIn: "true",
      disableDrive: "true",
      disableInvite: "true",
      disableShare: "true",
      noAudio: "false",
      noDisconnectAudio: "false"),
  super(key: key);
```

The real problem is `timer`. You assign timer on some callback into your class, I am not terribly sure what purpose it serves, but it doesn't seem like you can move this assignment to some other place. This means you are going to have to either live with the warning you are getting, or use a `StatefulWidget`:

```
class StartMeetingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ZoomOptions zoomOptions;
  final ZoomMeetingOptions meetingOptions;

StartMeetingWidget({Key key, meetingId})
  : zoomOptions = new ZoomOptions(
    domain: "zoom.us",
    appKey: "appKey",
    appSecret: "appSecret",
  ),
  meetingOptions = new ZoomMeetingOptions(
      userId: '<zoom_user_id>',
      displayName: 'Example display Name',
      meetingId: meetingId,
      zoomAccessToken: "<User zak>",
      zoomToken: "<user_token>",
      disableDialIn: "true",
      disableDrive: "true",
      disableInvite: "true",
      disableShare: "true",
      noAudio: "false",
      noDisconnectAudio: "false"),
  super(key: key);

  @override
  _StartMeetingWidgetState createState() => _StartMeetingWidgetState();
}

class _StartMeetingWidgetState extends State<StartMeetingWidget> {
  Timer timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you make the above changes, you will also have to change every reference to `this.zoomOptions` and `this.meetingOptions` into `widget.zoomOptions` and `widget.meetingOptions`.